# How can we consistently override/overload python's dot operator, `__getattrribute__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, getattribute, dot-operator

Assume that we are using `python 3.x` or newer, not `python 2.x`

Python, like many languages, has a dot-operator:

```python
# Create a new instance of the Rectangle class
robby = Rectangle(3, 10)

# INVOKE THE DOT OPERATOR       
x = robby.length
```

Python's dot-operator is ***sometimes*** implemented as `__getattribute__`.
The following is equivalent to `x = robby.length`:

```python
x = Rectangle.__getattribute__(robby, "length")
```

However, the dot-operator is ***not*** always implemented as `__getattribute__`.

Python has "***magic methods***"
A ***magic methods*** is any method whose name begins and ends with two underscore characters.
`__len__()` is an example of a magic method.

You can get a list of most of python's magic methods by executing the following code:

```python
print("\n".join(filter(lambda s: s.startswith("__"), dir(int))))
```

The output is:

```python
__abs__
__add__
__and__
__bool__
__ceil__
__class__
__delattr__
__dir__
__divmod__
__doc__
__eq__
__float__
[... truncated / abridged ...]
__rtruediv__
__rxor__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__sub__
__subclasshook__
__truediv__
__trunc__
__xor__
```

Suppose we write a class named `Rectangle`, sub-class of `object`.
Then my attempts to override `object.__getattribute__` inside of the `Rectangle` class, usually fail.

The following shows an example of a class where python sometimes ignores an overridden dot-operator:

```python
class Klass:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        return print

obj = Klass()

obj.append()  # WORKS FINE. `obj.append == print`
obj.delete()  # WORKS FINE. `obj.delete == print`
obj.length    # WORKS FINE
obj.x         # WORKS FINE

# None of the following work, because they
# invoke magic methods.  

# The following line is similar to:
#     x = Klass.__len__(obj)
len(obj)

# obj + 5
#     is similar to:
# x = Klass.__add__(obj, 5)
x = obj + 5

# The following line is similair to:
#     x = Klass.__radd__(obj, 2)
x = 2 + obj
```

There is more than one way to override python's dot operator.
What is an example of one way to do it which is readable, clean, and ***consistent***?

By ***consistent***, I mean that our custom dot operator gets called whenever `.` is used in source code, no matter whether the method is a magic method or not.

I am unwilling to manually type-in every single magic method under the sun.
I don't want to see thousands of lines of code which looks like:

```python
def __len__(*args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(args[0], "__len__")(*args, **kwargs)
```

I understand the distinction between `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`
Overriding `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__` is ***not*** the issue at hand.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup makes it seem like this is going to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

`__getattribute__` already does what you're literally asking for - overriding `__getattribute__` is all you need to handle all uses of the `.` operator. (Strictly speaking, Python will fall back to `__getattr__` if `__getattribute__` fails, but you don't have to worry about that as long as you don't implement `__getattr__`.)

---

You say you want your operator to be called "whenever `.` is used in source code", but `len`, `+`, and all the other things you're worried about **don't use `.`**. There is no `.` in `len(obj)`, `obj + 5`, or `2 + obj`.

Most magic method lookups **don't use attribute access**. If you actually look up `yourobj.__len__` or `yourobj.__add__`, that will go through attribute access, and your `__getattribute__` will be invoked, but when Python looks up a magic method to implement language functionality, it does a direct search of the object's type's MRO. The `.` operator is not involved.

There is no way to override magic method lookup. That's a hardcoded process with no override hook. The closest thing you can do is override individual magic methods to delegate to `__getattribute__`, but that's not the same thing as overriding magic method lookup (or overriding `.`), and it's easy to get infinite recursion bugs that way.

If all you really want to do is avoid repetitive individual magic method overrides, you could put them in a class decorator or mixin.

Comment: What if we define a subclass of `type` named `sype`. `sype` will override the default `__mro__` (method resolution order) defined in the `type` class. If I instantiate a class named `klass` from `sype`, then maybe magic methods will use `__getattribute__`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon: I'm not sure what the idea was supposed to be there, but it [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/xh1UgJ). Screwing with a class's MRO isn't going to change how special method lookup works. The MRO search will go through whatever weird MRO you set, but it'll still be a direct MRO search. (I've overridden the `mro` method, which computes the MRO, instead of the `__mro__` descriptor, because trying to override `__mro__` wouldn't even affect the actual MRO.)